# Parsing HTML String with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to use a jQuery selector on an HTML string? I'm trying to get the html contents of the div, foo.

```
var code = "<div id='foo'>1</div><div id='bar'>2</div>";
alert( $(code).html( ) ); // returns 1 (not sure how...)
```

How can I get the html contents of foo and of bar in two different statements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var code = $("<div id='foo'>1</div><div id='bar'>2</div>");

code.each(function() {
    alert( $(this).html() );
})
```

Comment: +1 jquery can take HTML inside $("..."). That's all you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`map`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.map)?

```
var code = "<div id='foo'>1</div><div id='bar'>2</div>";
var html = $(code).map(function() { return $(this).html() });
html[0]; // "1"
html[1]; // "2"
```

Is that what you mean?