# JQuery in internet explorer cant parse a string html

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer

I am trying to parse an HTML string in Internet Explorer using jQuery, based on: [Parsing HTML String with Ajax/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529464/parsing-html-string-with-ajax-jquery).
here is the code:

```
alert(result);
alert($(result));
```

The first alert prompts the HTML, but second alert just gives me Object. On firebug lite console it gives me a blank object: [] !!

```
console.log(result)
console.log($(result))
```

result is a big XHTML code, that is received through an AJAX call.
The same code works on Firefox..

Anyone has any idea why this could be happening?
Your help is much appreciated..!

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? isnt alert(html) what you want?

Comment: could you add some more code? How does the result is retrieved? post if you can a part of XHTML result code

Comment: Sorry, I dint mean to alert the html.. code: $(result).filter(function(){ return $(this).is("div") }).find("div.myclass").bind("trialthis",function(){filteredRes= filteredRes+$(this).html()}).trigger("trialthis"); What I finally want is the filteredRes html.. While debugging found out that the code is failing on that line!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the HTML code, it's hard to say, but I would have to guess that you're hitting the *"Unknown runtime error"* that occurs when you're invalidly trying to put an element where it's not allowed.

You see, jQuery builds the DOM from (X)HTML by creating a detached element and applying the (X)HTML to that element's `innerHTML` property.  FWIW, neither browsers care if you're passing XHTML or HTML, unless you're serving an XHTML mime type that would be giving you bigger problems.  If you consider the following plain JS code:

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = "<li>Test</li>";
```

Internet Explorer with throw a very unhelpful *"Unknown runtime error"*, whereas Firefox will do its best to salvage the invalid HTML.

I would recommend putting your XHTML through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org) and checking it for validation errors.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.. I was just simplifying the xhtml and trying.. here: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en_US" lang="en_US"><head><title>PageTitle</title></head><body class="bodyclass"></body></html> I have removed even the '\n's, as suggested in other questions, still nothing..

Comment: you are right, the original document is way malformed! 679 errors! Its a generated results page from a foswiki site.. but at least the HTML I have added above should work! even that is not working!

Comment: @Nikhil: that's because the code is stripped down to the *contents* of the body tag, which is empty in the code you've posted.  If you put some content in the `<body>` it should work.

Comment: Ohk.. there it goes.. Added a div in the body, added a character encoding meta in the head, and it worked..! Great! So that is how it is.. will have to work on making the foswiki page proper..! :) Thanks..