# IE8: In AJAX response, finding tag in response html is not working but works for other browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have ajax call as below

```
$.ajax({type: "GET",
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    beforeSend: function() {
        // some before code here
    }
    success: function(resp) {
       resp_html = $(resp).find('.somedivclass').html(); //doesnt work for IE8
       alert(resp_html);
    }
});
```

When I do alert for resp_html, for other browsers it works.
But for IE8 it doesnt? why ? Either of both below calls doesnt work for IE8.

```
       resp_html = $(resp).find('.somedivclass').html(); //doesnt work for IE8
```

Or

```
       resp_html = $('.somedivclass', resp).html(); //doesnt work for IE8
```

Comment: look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944569/jquery-in-internet-explorer-cant-parse-a-string-html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944569/jquery-in-internet-explorer-cant-parse-a-string-html)

Comment: wat is the error you see in console ? Did u see Freez's link ?Have a look at Freez's link, they have a work around there

Comment: check the content-type of your http response once. If it's `application/xhtml+xml` or if you have XHTML DTD in your page, that might be causing the issue.

Comment: I do get DTD in html. something like `DOCTYPE HTML ...`

Comment: @drt try to validate your HTML response with the W3C validator and check there are no errors

Comment: content-tupe is `text/html`