# Javascript ajax callback makes items list flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple list of Reminders that a user can click and drag into a "delete drop zone" one at a time. It makes an ajax call to my Webmatrix webservice to delete the item. This all works great. However, in the javascript or ajax callback I am retrieving the remaining items and displaying them back to the  list. For some reason, when this process happens the list flickers and then displays the newly updated amount. It kinda of steals the nice ajax effect away. Would be nice for the remaining items to sort of slide up to fill in the gap left from the item that was dragged away. Any help would be awesome and greatly appreciated!

Here's the code on jsFiddle: (Note: it is not a "working" fiddle example. Just a good place to put all the code snippets):

http://jsfiddle.net/cpeele00/4ugBt/

Answer (score 0):

You get the flash because you are clearing the entire list and then repopulating it.

```
var refreshReminderList = function(data) {
    $('#reminders-list').empty();
    $('#reminders-listTmpl').tmpl(data).appendTo('#reminders-list');
};
```

Instead of emptying it - iterate through the list and remove any elements that are not in the new data list. It looks like you return the actual html, instead return a list of ids (or some identifier.

```
//pseudocode
$('reminder-list li').each( function(){
     //if not in data list
     $(this).slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've tried it without the call to .empty() before and it still flickered, but I will try your suggestion. Yeah, I am returning the json from the webservice and then using that to populate the jquery template.

Comment: How would I return a list of ids verses the html? Don't I need to return that html to rebuild that list of <li> items? (sorry, little new to all this). thanks!

Comment: I suppose there are two ways to think about it. I guess originally I was assuming you were only removing things from the list, but it looks like things could be added or removed. If you received a list of ids then you would need to do two passes. One pass to remove old. One pass to insert new. For inserting you would need to generate the html client side. The other option is to receive html, but then parse it with jQuery to get id's out. See this SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529464/parsing-html-string-with-ajax-jquery

Comment: thanks @mrtsherman, but I'm not sure that that solution would work. I'm returning json data and stuffing that data into the appropriate jquery template. It iterates over that automatically and generates all the required <li> elements. I even did that manually to test it and it still flickered. Maybe you can post your solution in code so I can better understand why I would need to get the id's out. Thanks!