# How to get the specific div content from responseText which have complate Html page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am getting the whole html page in responseText, i just want to parse/
filter the responseText to
get a specific div say test and underlying contents. I would not
like to modify the server side code to send just required div in
`responseText`.

```
url: "Someurl",
datatype: "text/html",
success : function(responseText) 
{
    alert(responseText);
dat = $(data).filter("#test").html();
alert(dat);//getting null
$('#test').html(dat);

}
```

`responseText` contains

100's of HTML lines....
....
     ....many more div tags and other
    tags 
....
100's of HTML lines

I'm using jquery and i tried

```
$(responseText).filter("#test").html();
```

and used find too

Comment: What do you mean you "used find too?"  How did you use it?

Comment: `$(data)` where is `data` defined ?

Comment: possible answer could be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529464/parsing-html-string-with-ajax-jquery?rq=1

Looks worth a try

Comment: @jerome that is responseText not data.

Comment: @Riju Its getting all the divs how can i get a particular div...Please help me out.

Comment: @SheikAbdulCaderSoofi : i think u missed my answer below..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only html in the response AND your intention is to pinpoint a DIV using a unique ID, then it might be even easier than the example I gave earlier.

Try something like this

```
var myHtml = $(responseText).find('#test').html();
//alert(myHtml); -- optional, just to verify
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        Hi use below line it will work

         $(responseText).find("#test").html();
```

Comment: if 'test' id is span or label means use .text method. div means use .html method

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using find() ?

```
$(responseText).find('#test').html(); // to change the html
```

or

```
$(responseText).find('#test').text(); // to just get the content
```

Comment: I guess .html() will be more useful here since the element may need to be manipulated further.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be dataType not datatype: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
And set the dataType to "html" for this method, not "text/html"

```
 dataType = "html";
```